# How to remove whitespace between dash dbc items?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I've been working on a dashboard for some time now and have been unable to remove a pretty large piece of whitespace between one dbc.Row element (containing two columns) and the next dcc.markdown element. If you look at the image below (zoomed out the proportions look a little funny), you'll see the enormous piece of whitespace I can't seem to remove.

[image]

I've tried all sorts of things to get rid of it including a combination of the following attributes `style={'margin-bottom': '1em'}, className="h-5", no_gutters=True` but nothing seems to work. Is it possible, that Dash is applying some sort of page break that I'm unaware of?

My code looks as follows:

```
    dbc.Row([dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='table1', figure=
                go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['Accumulated Performance','(gross, in %)']),
                        cells=dict(values=[a, b]))],
                        layout=go.Layout(margin={'t': 25, 'b': 5, 'l': 10, 'r': 25}
                        )))
                             ),
                     dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='table2', figure=
                        go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['Selected Risk Metrics', '']),
                        cells=dict(values=[['Sharpe Ratio 1-y','Volatility 1-y','Information Ratio 1-y',
                                            'Max 1-m drawdown (since inception)'],
                                           ['Value', 'Value', 'Value', 'Value']]))],
                        layout=go.Layout(margin={'t': 25, 'b': 5, 'l': 10, 'r': 25},
                        )))
                             )
                     ], style={'margin-bottom': '1em'}, className="h-5", no_gutters=True),

            dcc.Markdown('''
            #### Investment Philosophy
            
            Include some text describing my investment philosophy.  
            '''),

            dcc.Graph(id='indexed_return_graph')
```

Comment: Maybe you apply style to wrong component. You can use chrome elements to find out that white space belongs to which part of dashboard components. Then apply style parameters to that component.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add a style argument to the code **style={'height': '175px'}** for each of the two columns.

```
dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='table1', figure=
            go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['Accumulated Performance','(gross, in %)']),
            cells=dict(values=[a, b]))],
            layout=go.Layout(margin={'t': 5, 'b': 0, 'l': 10, 'r': 0, 'pad':10}
            )), style={'height': '175px'})),
        
        dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='table2', figure=
            go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['Selected Risk Metrics', '']),
            cells=dict(values=[['Sharpe Ratio 1-y','Volatility 1-y','Information Ratio 1-y',
            'Max 1-m drawdown (since inception)'],
            ['Value', 'Value', 'Value', 'Value']]))],
            layout=go.Layout(margin={'t': 5, 'b': 0, 'l': 10, 'r': 0, 'pad':10}
            )), style={'height': '175px'}))
         ])
```